# Connecting two Android applications

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I was developing a dictionary app which could be accessed in a third party app. The basic idea is that whenever you are using any app(say viewing a webpage or messaging) and you want to know the meaning of any word then all you have to do is select that word and share it to my app. I have developed most of the code but the thing is I am not able to get a mechanism to share the word from the third party app(say a messenger app)into my app.

Whenever you select a word it should give you an option called "share to dictionary"  and this should redirect you to the dictionary(my app) and display the meaning of the selected word. I just wanted a mechanism where the share option would appear in a third party application soon after selecting the word ,similar to the "cut","copy" options that appear on selecting a word.

Any help is appreciated guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it in following manner

1-: You can use sharedprference as public it is the global place for save data in application level.

2-: Create a file in internal storage one application is write and another is read or vise versa.

3-: Store data in the web and make set and get api.

and for more information you can read

[Storage option in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)